# Got empty object when call news from my extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, tx-news

I have to create an extension to filter the news. So I build an extension with news model. My model looks like

```
class News extends \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News
{        
}
```

I have to list all news from my extension. So I called the

```
$this->newsRepository->findAll();
```

From my controller.But it returns an empty object.So I write a custom function `FilterNews()` here is my code

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->matching(
    $query->equals('uid', 1)
);
return $query->execute();
```

There is a news with `uid = 1`.But it returns empty. How can I access news?

I included the following function in my repository

```
     public function initializeObject() {
            $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
            $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE );
            $querySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(TRUE);   
$querySettings->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(array('disabled','starttime'));
            $querySettings->setIncludeDeleted(FALSE);
            $querySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);

            $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution: Add table mapping to your model see this extension: https://github.com/Schweriner/tgm_lazynews/blob/master/ext_typoscript_setup.txt

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your storagePid settings for you own extension is set to the pid of your tx_news folder:

```
plugin.my_extkey {
  persistence {
    storagePid = xxx
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can say your query it should not respect the storage pid:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$querySettings = $query->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$query->setQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

Comment: I already included the above code in my repository.But it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Always forgetting the same: Do you "return $query->execute();" ? ;-)

Comment: In your code above is no "return"-statement. So you are sure your function does return something?